# Form control react bootstrap textarea editable on open

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-form

Currently, I'm using the following field to get input from the user
[details_field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g66rh.png)

```
    <Form.Label>Details</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control
      type="text"
      readOnly
      value={
        responseObject[item.user_response_details.id]
          ? responseObject[item.user_response_details.id].comments
          : item.user_response_details.comments
      }
      onClick={(e) => {
        setModalShow(true);      // Sets the visibility of the modal                        
      }}
      onFocusCapture={() => {
        setPrevState(responseObject);
      }}
      onChange={(e) => {
        setComments(e.target.value);
      }}
      onBlur={() => {
        console.log(newComment);
        if (comments && comments !== '' && newComment) {
          dispatch(IncrementCompletedActivityCount({ count: 1 }));
          setNew(false);
        }
      }}
      required
    />
    <Form.Text>
    </Form.Text>
```

On clicking on the field the modal is shown but to enter text in details popup I have to provide an extra click to start editing the details
[details_box_popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNypZ.png)

```
{modalShow && (
  <DetailsModal
    id={activityId}
    item={currentItem}
    loginUserGroups={loginUserGroups}
    onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
  />
)}
```

Can this be implemented without the extra click that need to be provided while adding details in the

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While displaying the modal DetailsModal local reference can be created using `useRef` hook as follows:

```
DetailsModal(props) {
  const elementRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {

    elementRef.current.focus();
  }, []);
```

```
<Form.Group className="mb-0" controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
              <Form.Control
                as="textarea"
                onChange={(e) => {

                  setComments(e.target.value);
                }}
                rows={7}
                ref={elementRef} // using the reference created
              />
            </Form.Group>
```

This will bring in the focus on the field without onClick